# ComboBox in DataGrid (c# wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf

sample combobox:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn
Header="Status"
SelectedItemBinding="{Binding status}"
ItemsSource="{Binding status}"
Width="98.8"
/>
```

sourse data on mysql web server

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select id,user_name,user_phone,user_email,payment_method,amount,user_comment,delivery_city,delivery_address,status from `request`", conn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

so I build a table, all data is there except, the `Status` is empty, why?

Comment: No uppercase issue? WPF is case sensitive is it Status or status?

Comment: it is a bit weird that you are binding the SelectedItem and the ItemsSource to the same Property. the ItemsSource should be bound to a collection, and SelectedItem to a single element. Otherwise we need to have more details. I am just guessing now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ItemsSource needs to be a collection.   See the bottom of this link if you need an enum collection.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn.aspx

If the collection is dynamic then you need a class with a property that returns a collection.